# AJAX JQuery GET gives success but doesnt update the table

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, get

I'm trying to update readed when a user clicks on an notification in the inbox. I saw on internet it should be really easy with AJAX and jquery, but i'm getting a weird problem with it. After i click the AJAX responds with success, but when i looked in my database it wasn't updated. Then i tried to do it by hand and gave the right values for it in the link. Afterwards i'm getting the responds success and the database was updateded with success too. So the problem must be the AJAX but i don't know what i did wrong.

read.msg.php

```
include("db-conct.php");

$AID = $_GET['aid'];
$msgID = $_GET['msgid'];

$update = "UPDATE notify SET readed = 1 WHERE acc_ID = $AID AND ID = $msgID";

if ($conn->query($update) == TRUE) {
echo "Succes!";
}else{
echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

The AJAX script:

```
$(document).on("click","#notify-item",function(){

    var aid = "<?php echo $aid; ?>";
    var msgid = "<?php echo $notifID; ?>";

    $.ajax({

        type:"POST", //GET - update query should be POST
        url: "read.msg.php",  //your php end point
        data: 'aid=' + aid + '&msgid=' + msgid, 
        success: function(data){ //if success
            alert("Record successfully updated");
        }

    })
});
```

I hope someone can see the problem.

ADDED PICTURES:

[image: MYSQL DB WITH readed STILL 0]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are not checking what is the response from the script and just alerting ("Record Successfully Updated");

You should do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "read.msg.php",  
    data: {aid:aid ,msgid:msgid},
    success: function(data){
                if(data=="success"){
                alert("Record successfully updated");
                }
                else{
                alert("Some Error");
                }
            } 

});
```

php script:

```
<?php
include("db-conct.php");
@extract($_POST);
$aid = $_POST['aid'];
$msgid = $_POST['msgid'];

$update = "UPDATE notify SET readed = 1 WHERE acc_ID = '$aid' AND ID = $'msgid'";

if ($conn->query($update) == TRUE) {
echo "success";
}else{
echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

Comment: Soo i tried it and now im getting indeed the Some Error respond, but it looks like that the ajax has no permission or something. Because when i do it by hand the db updated and otherwise not.

Comment: try this data format: `data: {aid:aid,msgid:msgid}`

Comment: I tried you're data format but still getting the error respond. really weird. it seems like the ajax doesnt have permission. its all fine when i do it by hand @Rahul

Comment: I'm going to check

Comment: The responds now is success, but the table isn't updated. Its really weird

Comment: It can't be, check your table row with the respective data you are sending.

Comment: Still not updated and as i said when i do it with the link and the values everything is working fine

Comment: check the values of aid and  msgid before sending in jquery

Comment: print aid,msgid in console by `console.log(aid+"-"+msgid)`

Comment: 26-30 The're sended with it

Comment: @ConstantBrummer add this line beneath include in php: `@extract($_POST);`

Comment: @Arun i can see it now in the network tab by the line of rahul, but the table still isn't updating. it really weird

Comment: @Rahul now i can see it in the network tab, but still not updated the table

Comment: @ConstantBrummer have you changed the GET to POST in your php file as I updated. And still are you receiving success response and table isn't updated !

Comment: Its still POST and still receiving success responds and table still not updated. Its really weird i tought ajax would be easy :p

Comment: There is something we are missing !

Comment: @Rahul Must really be something we are missing. Should i show what i've got now

Comment: @Rahul i've found the solution! the row readed was a ENUM so it won't work for some reason. i've changed readed to int and now everything is working fine. Thank you for ur effort and time

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click","#notify-item",function(){

var aid = "<?php echo $aid; ?>";
var msgid = "<?php echo $notifID; ?>";

$.ajax({

    type:"POST", //GET - update query should be POST
    url: "read.msg.php",  //your php end point
    data: {'aid':aid ,'msgid':msgid}, // this is the data format
    success: function(data){ //if success
        alert("Record successfully updated");
    }

})
```

});

Comment: Its still not working yet. I am now seeing its an error but when i do it by hand its all working. really weird

Comment: what do you mean by do it by hand?

Comment: when i go to the link with the values in the link like read.msg.php?aid=26&msgid=30 i

Comment: then it works but when i do it in the ajax it gives an error

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is in your php processing code.

You have to make sure the data not empty before updating the database.

Wrap your code using `isset` on the POST values, and try to echoing it for testing.

If it is empty, it mean there's problem on your javascript that supply the data before posted.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['aid']) && isset($_POST['msgid'])) {

  //echo $_POST['aid'].' / '.$_POST['msgid'];

  include("db-conct.php");

  $aid = $_POST['aid'];
  $msgid = $_POST['msgid'];

  $update = "UPDATE notify SET readed = 1 WHERE acc_ID = '$aid' AND ID = $'msgid'";

  if ($conn->query($update) == TRUE) {

    echo "success";

  }else{

    echo "Error: " . $conn->error;

  }
}
?>
```

Happy coding!